# Error: "String index out of range" showing vulnerabilities in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

We're getting an error in SonarQube 6.7.4 when we try to show the vulnerabilities.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Go to the specific project dashboard
2. Click on the vulnerabilities number (there're 485 vulnerabilities)

When SonarQube try to access https://SONAR-SERVER/project/issues?id=PROJECT-ID&resolved=false&types=VULNERABILITY the following message is shown in the screen:

> An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator

In the SONAR-HOME/logs/web.log file we get the following error:

```
2020.01.15 16:50:04 ERROR web[AW7a+NqnB0ZV0bF3AXLJ][o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://SONAR-SERVER/api/issues/search?componentKeys=PROJECT-ID&s=FILE_LINE&resolved=false&types=VULNERABILITY&ps=100&facets=severities%2Ctypes&additionalFields=_all
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.charAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:237)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.charAt(StringBuilder.java:76)
    at org.sonar.markdown.HtmlBlockquoteChannel$QuotedLineElementChannel.searchIndexOfFirstCharacter(HtmlBlockquoteChannel.java:86)
    at org.sonar.markdown.HtmlBlockquoteChannel$QuotedLineElementChannel.consume(HtmlBlockquoteChannel.java:75)
    at org.sonar.markdown.HtmlBlockquoteChannel$QuotedLineElementChannel.consume(HtmlBlockquoteChannel.java:63)
    at org.sonar.channel.RegexChannel.consume(RegexChannel.java:46)
    at org.sonar.markdown.HtmlBlockquoteChannel.consume(HtmlBlockquoteChannel.java:51)
    at org.sonar.markdown.HtmlBlockquoteChannel.consume(HtmlBlockquoteChannel.java:41)
    at org.sonar.channel.ChannelDispatcher.consume(ChannelDispatcher.java:76)
    at org.sonar.markdown.Markdown.convert(Markdown.java:52)
    at org.sonar.markdown.Markdown.convertToHtml(Markdown.java:57)
    at org.sonar.server.issue.ws.SearchResponseFormat.formatIssueComments(SearchResponseFormat.java:278)
    at org.sonar.server.issue.ws.SearchResponseFormat.lambda$formatIssues$0(SearchResponseFormat.java:150)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.sonar.server.issue.ws.SearchResponseFormat.formatIssues(SearchResponseFormat.java:140)
    at org.sonar.server.issue.ws.SearchResponseFormat.formatSearch(SearchResponseFormat.java:87)
    at org.sonar.server.issue.ws.SearchAction.doHandle(SearchAction.java:366)
    at org.sonar.server.issue.ws.SearchAction.handle(SearchAction.java:318)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:103)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:86)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:87)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:72)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Notes:

- This error is happening in only one specific project.
- The bugs, new bugs and new vulnerabilities links are working pretty well.

Comment: This could be a bug. Have a look [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-markdown/src/main/java/org/sonar/markdown/HtmlBlockquoteChannel.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by deleting the original project and recreating it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after entering a comment to an issue. The message I received from SonarQube as "*An error has occured. Please contact your administrator.*" When investigating it I found the following [bug report from 2015](http://web.archive.org/web/20150508060453/http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6032):

> When a line of Markdown text only contains the ">" character followed by a space, a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.
>
> See http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException-when-parsing-comment-Sonarqube-4-5-1-tt5031350.html

Indeed I had written a comment that contained an empty blockquote followed by a space with no further text `>` . After digging through SonarQube's source code I found that the comments are stored in the table `issue_changes`.

I queried the data `select * from issue_changes where change_data like '%> %';` and manually changed the offending comment to not contain blockquotes any more. After that everything was working fine again.